# c# / asp.net solution for converting strings to html entities (keyword representation)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm converting multilingual strings to html. I **have to** use html entities using their keyword representation not *decimal* or *hex*. I currently use following implementation I just wonder if ASP.NET does have a on-board library which I can use.

```
private static readonly List < Tuple < string, string, string >> _htmlEntities = new List < Tuple < string, string, string >> {
 Tuple.Create("&", "&amp;", "&#38;"), // Ampersand
 Tuple.Create("<", "&lt;", "&#60;"), // Less-than
 Tuple.Create(">", "&gt;", "&#62;"), // Greater than
 Tuple.Create("À", "&Agrave;", "&#192;"), // Capital a with grave accent
 Tuple.Create("Á", "&Aacute;", "&#193;"), // Capital a with acute accent
 Tuple.Create("Â", "&Acirc;", "&#194;"), // Capital a with circumflex accent
 Tuple.Create("Ã", "&Atilde;", "&#195;"), // Capital a with tilde
 Tuple.Create("Ä", "&Auml;", "&#196;"), // Capital a with umlaut
 Tuple.Create("Å", "&Aring;", "&#197;"), // Capital a with ring
 Tuple.Create("Æ", "&AElig;", "&#198;"), // Capital ae
 Tuple.Create("Ç", "&Ccedil;", "&#199;"), // Capital c with cedilla
 Tuple.Create("È", "&Egrave;", "&#200;"), // Capital e with grave accent
 Tuple.Create("É", "&Eacute;", "&#201;"), // Capital e with acute accent
 Tuple.Create("Ê", "&Ecirc;", "&#202;"), // Capital e with circumflex accent
 Tuple.Create("Ë", "&Euml;", "&#203;"), // Capital e with umlaut
 Tuple.Create("Ì", "&Igrave;", "&#204;"), // Capital i with grave accent
 Tuple.Create("Í", "&Iacute;", "&#205;"), // Capital i with accute accent
 Tuple.Create("Î", "&Icirc;", "&#206;"), // Capital i with circumflex accent
 Tuple.Create("Ï", "&Iuml;", "&#207;"), // Capital i with umlaut
 Tuple.Create("Ð", "&ETH;", "&#208;"), // Capital eth (Icelandic)
 Tuple.Create("Ñ", "&Ntilde;", "&#209;"), // Capital n with tilde
 Tuple.Create("Ò", "&Ograve;", "&#210;"), // Capital o with grave accent
 Tuple.Create("Ó", "&Oacute;", "&#211;"), // Capital o with accute accent
 Tuple.Create("Ô", "&Ocirc;", "&#212;"), // Capital o with circumflex accent
 Tuple.Create("Õ", "&Otilde;", "&#213;"), // Capital o with tilde
 Tuple.Create("Ö", "&Ouml;", "&#214;"), // Capital o with umlaut
 Tuple.Create("Ø", "&Oslash;", "&#216;"), // Capital o with slash
 Tuple.Create("Ù", "&Ugrave;", "&#217;"), // Capital u with grave accent
 Tuple.Create("Ú", "&Uacute;", "&#218;"), // Capital u with acute accent
 Tuple.Create("Û", "&Ucirc;", "&#219;"), // Capital u with circumflex accent
 Tuple.Create("Ü", "&Uuml;", "&#220;"), // Capital u with umlaut
 Tuple.Create("Ý", "&Yacute;", "&#221;"), // Capital y with acute accent
 Tuple.Create("Þ", "&THORN;", "&#222;"), // Capital thorn (Icelandic)
 Tuple.Create("ß", "&szlig;", "&#223;"), // Lowercase sharp s (German)
 Tuple.Create("à", "&agrave;", "&#224;"), // Lowercase a with grave accent
 Tuple.Create("á", "&aacute;", "&#225;"), // Lowercase a with acute accent
 Tuple.Create("â", "&acirc;", "&#226;"), // Lowercase a with circumflex accent
 Tuple.Create("ã", "&atilde;", "&#227;"), // Lowercase a with tilde
 Tuple.Create("ä", "&auml;", "&#228;"), // Lowercase a with umlaut
 Tuple.Create("å", "&aring;", "&#229;"), // Lowercase a with ring
 Tuple.Create("æ", "&aelig;", "&#230;"), // Lowercase ae
 Tuple.Create("ç", "&ccedil;", "&#231;"), // Lowercase c with cedilla
 Tuple.Create("è", "&egrave;", "&#232;"), // Lowercase e with grave accent
 Tuple.Create("é", "&eacute;", "&#233;"), // Lowercase e with acute accent
 Tuple.Create("ê", "&ecirc;", "&#234;"), // Lowercase e with circumflex accent
 Tuple.Create("ë", "&euml;", "&#235;"), // Lowercase e with umlaut
 Tuple.Create("ì", "&igrave;", "&#236;"), // Lowercase i with grave accent
 Tuple.Create("í", "&iacute;", "&#237;"), // Lowercase i with acute accent
 Tuple.Create("î", "&icirc;", "&#238;"), // Lowercase i with circumflex accent
 Tuple.Create("ï", "&iuml;", "&#239;"), // Lowercase i with umlaut
 Tuple.Create("ð", "&eth;", "&#240;"), // Lowercase eth (Icelandic)
 Tuple.Create("ñ", "&ntilde;", "&#241;"), // Lowercase n with tilde
 Tuple.Create("ò", "&ograve;", "&#242;"), // Lowercase o with grave accent
 Tuple.Create("ó", "&oacute;", "&#243;"), // Lowercase o with acute accent
 Tuple.Create("ô", "&ocirc;", "&#244;"), // Lowercase o with circumflex accent
 Tuple.Create("õ", "&otilde;", "&#245;"), // Lowercase o with tilde
 Tuple.Create("ö", "&ouml;", "&#246;"), // Lowercase o with umlaut
 Tuple.Create("ø", "&oslash;", "&#248;"), // Lowercase o with slash
 Tuple.Create("ù", "&ugrave;", "&#249;"), // Lowercase u with grave accent
 Tuple.Create("ú", "&uacute;", "&#250;"), // Lowercase u with acute accent
 Tuple.Create("û", "&ucirc;", "&#251;"), // Lowercase u with circumflex accent
 Tuple.Create("ü", "&uuml;", "&#252;"), // Lowercase u with umlaut
 Tuple.Create("ý", "&yacute;", "&#253;"), // Lowercase y with acute accent
 Tuple.Create("þ", "&thorn;", "&#254;"), // Lowercase thorn (Icelandic)
 Tuple.Create("ÿ", "&yuml;", "&#255;"), // Lowercase y with umlaut
 Tuple.Create(" ", "&nbsp;", "&#160;"), // Non-breaking space
 Tuple.Create("¡", "&iexcl;", "&#161;"), // Inverted exclamation mark
 Tuple.Create("¢", "&cent;", "&#162;"), // Cent
 Tuple.Create("£", "&pound;", "&#163;"), // Pound
 Tuple.Create("¤", "&curren;", "&#164;"), // Currency
 Tuple.Create("¥", "&yen;", "&#165;"), // Yen
 Tuple.Create("¦", "&brvbar;", "&#166;"), // Broken vertical bar
 Tuple.Create("§", "&sect;", "&#167;"), // Section
 Tuple.Create("¨", "&uml;", "&#168;"), // Spacing diaeresis
 Tuple.Create("©", "&copy;", "&#169;"), // Copyright
 Tuple.Create("ª", "&ordf;", "&#170;"), // Feminine ordinal indicator
 Tuple.Create("«", "&laquo;", "&#171;"), // Opening/Left angle quotation mark
 Tuple.Create("¬", "&not;", "&#172;"), // Negation
 Tuple.Create("­", "&shy;", "&#173;"), // Soft hyphen
 Tuple.Create("®", "&reg;", "&#174;"), // Registered trademark
 Tuple.Create("¯", "&macr;", "&#175;"), // Spacing macron
 Tuple.Create("°", "&deg;", "&#176;"), // Degree
 Tuple.Create("±", "&plusmn;", "&#177;"), // Plus or minus
 Tuple.Create("²", "&sup2;", "&#178;"), // Superscript 2
 Tuple.Create("³", "&sup3;", "&#179;"), // Superscript 3
 Tuple.Create("´", "&acute;", "&#180;"), // Spacing acute
 Tuple.Create("µ", "&micro;", "&#181;"), // Micro
 Tuple.Create("¶", "&para;", "&#182;"), // Paragraph
 Tuple.Create("¸", "&cedil;", "&#184;"), // Spacing cedilla
 Tuple.Create("¹", "&sup1;", "&#185;"), // Superscript 1
 Tuple.Create("º", "&ordm;", "&#186;"), // Masculine ordinal indicator
 Tuple.Create("»", "&raquo;", "&#187;"), // Closing/Right angle quotation mark
 Tuple.Create("¼", "&frac14;", "&#188;"), // Fraction 1/4
 Tuple.Create("½", "&frac12;", "&#189;"), // Fraction 1/2
 Tuple.Create("¾", "&frac34;", "&#190;"), // Fraction 3/4
 Tuple.Create("¿", "&iquest;", "&#191;"), // Inverted question mark
 Tuple.Create("×", "&times;", "&#215;"), // Multiplication
 Tuple.Create("÷", "&divide;", "&#247;"), // Divide
 Tuple.Create("∀", "&forall;", "&#8704;"), // For all
 Tuple.Create("∂", "&part;", "&#8706;"), // Part
 Tuple.Create("∃", "&exist;", "&#8707;"), // Exist
 Tuple.Create("∅", "&empty;", "&#8709;"), // Empty
 Tuple.Create("∇", "&nabla;", "&#8711;"), // Nabla
 Tuple.Create("∈", "&isin;", "&#8712;"), // Is in
 Tuple.Create("∉", "&notin;", "&#8713;"), // Not in
 Tuple.Create("∋", "&ni;", "&#8715;"), // Ni
 Tuple.Create("∏", "&prod;", "&#8719;"), // Product
 Tuple.Create("∑", "&sum;", "&#8721;"), // Sum
 Tuple.Create("−", "&minus;", "&#8722;"), // Minus
 Tuple.Create("∗", "&lowast;", "&#8727;"), // Asterisk (Lowast)
 Tuple.Create("√", "&radic;", "&#8730;"), // Square root
 Tuple.Create("∝", "&prop;", "&#8733;"), // Proportional to
 Tuple.Create("∞", "&infin;", "&#8734;"), // Infinity
 Tuple.Create("∠", "&ang;", "&#8736;"), // Angle
 Tuple.Create("∧", "&and;", "&#8743;"), // And
 Tuple.Create("∨", "&or;", "&#8744;"), // Or
 Tuple.Create("∩", "&cap;", "&#8745;"), // Cap
 Tuple.Create("∪", "&cup;", "&#8746;"), // Cup
 Tuple.Create("∫", "&int;", "&#8747;"), // Integral
 Tuple.Create("∴", "&there4;", "&#8756;"), // Therefore
 Tuple.Create("∼", "&sim;", "&#8764;"), // Similar to
 Tuple.Create("≅", "&cong;", "&#8773;"), // Congurent to
 Tuple.Create("≈", "&asymp;", "&#8776;"), // Almost equal
 Tuple.Create("≠", "&ne;", "&#8800;"), // Not equal
 Tuple.Create("≡", "&equiv;", "&#8801;"), // Equivalent
 Tuple.Create("≤", "&le;", "&#8804;"), // Less or equal
 Tuple.Create("≥", "&ge;", "&#8805;"), // Greater or equal
 Tuple.Create("⊂", "&sub;", "&#8834;"), // Subset of
 Tuple.Create("⊃", "&sup;", "&#8835;"), // Superset of
 Tuple.Create("⊄", "&nsub;", "&#8836;"), // Not subset of
 Tuple.Create("⊆", "&sube;", "&#8838;"), // Subset or equal
 Tuple.Create("⊇", "&supe;", "&#8839;"), // Superset or equal
 Tuple.Create("⊕", "&oplus;", "&#8853;"), // Circled plus
 Tuple.Create("⊗", "&otimes;", "&#8855;"), // Circled times
 Tuple.Create("⊥", "&perp;", "&#8869;"), // Perpendicular
 Tuple.Create("⋅", "&sdot;", "&#8901;"), // Dot operator
 Tuple.Create("Α", "&Alpha;", "&#913;"), // Alpha
 Tuple.Create("Β", "&Beta;", "&#914;"), // Beta
 Tuple.Create("Γ", "&Gamma;", "&#915;"), // Gamma
 Tuple.Create("Δ", "&Delta;", "&#916;"), // Delta
 Tuple.Create("Ε", "&Epsilon;", "&#917;"), // Epsilon
 Tuple.Create("Ζ", "&Zeta;", "&#918;"), // Zeta
 Tuple.Create("Η", "&Eta;", "&#919;"), // Eta
 Tuple.Create("Θ", "&Theta;", "&#920;"), // Theta
 Tuple.Create("Ι", "&Iota;", "&#921;"), // Iota
 Tuple.Create("Κ", "&Kappa;", "&#922;"), // Kappa
 Tuple.Create("Λ", "&Lambda;", "&#923;"), // Lambda
 Tuple.Create("Μ", "&Mu;", "&#924;"), // Mu
 Tuple.Create("Ν", "&Nu;", "&#925;"), // Nu
 Tuple.Create("Ξ", "&Xi;", "&#926;"), // Xi
 Tuple.Create("Ο", "&Omicron;", "&#927;"), // Omicron
 Tuple.Create("Π", "&Pi;", "&#928;"), // Pi
 Tuple.Create("Ρ", "&Rho;", "&#929;"), // Rho
 Tuple.Create("Σ", "&Sigma;", "&#931;"), // Sigma
 Tuple.Create("Τ", "&Tau;", "&#932;"), // Tau
 Tuple.Create("Υ", "&Upsilon;", "&#933;"), // Upsilon
 Tuple.Create("Φ", "&Phi;", "&#934;"), // Phi
 Tuple.Create("Χ", "&Chi;", "&#935;"), // Chi
 Tuple.Create("Ψ", "&Psi;", "&#936;"), // Psi
 Tuple.Create("Ω", "&Omega;", "&#937;"), // Omega
 Tuple.Create("α", "&alpha;", "&#945;"), // alpha
 Tuple.Create("β", "&beta;", "&#946;"), // beta
 Tuple.Create("γ", "&gamma;", "&#947;"), // gamma
 Tuple.Create("δ", "&delta;", "&#948;"), // delta
 Tuple.Create("ε", "&epsilon;", "&#949;"), // epsilon
 Tuple.Create("ζ", "&zeta;", "&#950;"), // zeta
 Tuple.Create("η", "&eta;", "&#951;"), // eta
 Tuple.Create("θ", "&theta;", "&#952;"), // theta
 Tuple.Create("ι", "&iota;", "&#953;"), // iota
 Tuple.Create("κ", "&kappa;", "&#954;"), // kappa
 Tuple.Create("λ", "&lambda;", "&#955;"), // lambda
 Tuple.Create("μ", "&mu;", "&#956;"), // mu
 Tuple.Create("ν", "&nu;", "&#957;"), // nu
 Tuple.Create("ξ", "&xi;", "&#958;"), // xi
 Tuple.Create("ο", "&omicron;", "&#959;"), // omicron
 Tuple.Create("π", "&pi;", "&#960;"), // pi
 Tuple.Create("ρ", "&rho;", "&#961;"), // rho
 Tuple.Create("ς", "&sigmaf;", "&#962;"), // sigmaf
 Tuple.Create("σ", "&sigma;", "&#963;"), // sigma
 Tuple.Create("τ", "&tau;", "&#964;"), // tau
 Tuple.Create("υ", "&upsilon;", "&#965;"), // upsilon
 Tuple.Create("φ", "&phi;", "&#966;"), // phi
 Tuple.Create("χ", "&chi;", "&#967;"), // chi
 Tuple.Create("ψ", "&psi;", "&#968;"), // psi
 Tuple.Create("ω", "&omega;", "&#969;"), // omega
 Tuple.Create("ϑ", "&thetasym;", "&#977;"), // Theta symbol
 Tuple.Create("ϒ", "&upsih;", "&#978;"), // Upsilon symbol
 Tuple.Create("ϖ", "&piv;", "&#982;"), // Pi symbol
 Tuple.Create("Œ", "&OElig;", "&#338;"), // Uppercase ligature OE
 Tuple.Create("œ", "&oelig;", "&#339;"), // Lowercase ligature OE
 Tuple.Create("Š", "&Scaron;", "&#352;"), // Uppercase S with caron
 Tuple.Create("š", "&scaron;", "&#353;"), // Lowercase S with caron
 Tuple.Create("Ÿ", "&Yuml;", "&#376;"), // Capital Y with diaeres
 Tuple.Create("ƒ", "&fnof;", "&#402;"), // Lowercase with hook
 Tuple.Create("ˆ", "&circ;", "&#710;"), // Circumflex accent
 Tuple.Create("˜", "&tilde;", "&#732;"), // Tilde
 Tuple.Create(" ", "&ensp;", "&#8194;"), // En space
 Tuple.Create(" ", "&emsp;", "&#8195;"), // Em space
 Tuple.Create(" ", "&thinsp;", "&#8201;"), // Thin space
 Tuple.Create("‌", "&zwnj;", "&#8204;"), // Zero width non-joiner
 Tuple.Create("‍", "&zwj;", "&#8205;"), // Zero width joiner
 Tuple.Create("‎", "&lrm;", "&#8206;"), // Left-to-right mark
 Tuple.Create("‏", "&rlm;", "&#8207;"), // Right-to-left mark
 Tuple.Create("–", "&ndash;", "&#8211;"), // En dash
 Tuple.Create("—", "&mdash;", "&#8212;"), // Em dash
 Tuple.Create("‘", "&lsquo;", "&#8216;"), // Left single quotation mark
 Tuple.Create("’", "&rsquo;", "&#8217;"), // Right single quotation mark
 Tuple.Create("‚", "&sbquo;", "&#8218;"), // Single low-9 quotation mark
 Tuple.Create("“", "&ldquo;", "&#8220;"), // Left double quotation mark
 Tuple.Create("”", "&rdquo;", "&#8221;"), // Right double quotation mark
 Tuple.Create("„", "&bdquo;", "&#8222;"), // Double low-9 quotation mark
 Tuple.Create("†", "&dagger;", "&#8224;"), // Dagger
 Tuple.Create("‡", "&Dagger;", "&#8225;"), // Double dagger
 Tuple.Create("•", "&bull;", "&#8226;"), // Bullet
 Tuple.Create("…", "&hellip;", "&#8230;"), // Horizontal ellipsis
 Tuple.Create("‰", "&permil;", "&#8240;"), // Per mille
 Tuple.Create("′", "&prime;", "&#8242;"), // Minutes (Degrees)
 Tuple.Create("″", "&Prime;", "&#8243;"), // Seconds (Degrees)
 Tuple.Create("‹", "&lsaquo;", "&#8249;"), // Single left angle quotation
 Tuple.Create("›", "&rsaquo;", "&#8250;"), // Single right angle quotation
 Tuple.Create("‾", "&oline;", "&#8254;"), // Overline
 Tuple.Create("€", "&euro;", "&#8364;"), // Euro
 Tuple.Create("™", "&trade;", "&#8482;"), // Trademark
 Tuple.Create("←", "&larr;", "&#8592;"), // Left arrow
 Tuple.Create("↑", "&uarr;", "&#8593;"), // Up arrow
 Tuple.Create("→", "&rarr;", "&#8594;"), // Right arrow
 Tuple.Create("↓", "&darr;", "&#8595;"), // Down arrow
 Tuple.Create("↔", "&harr;", "&#8596;"), // Left right arrow
 Tuple.Create("↵", "&crarr;", "&#8629;"), // Carriage return arrow
 Tuple.Create("⌈", "&lceil;", "&#8968;"), // Left ceiling
 Tuple.Create("⌉", "&rceil;", "&#8969;"), // Right ceiling
 Tuple.Create("⌊", "&lfloor;", "&#8970;"), // Left floor
 Tuple.Create("⌋", "&rfloor;", "&#8971;"), // Right floor
 Tuple.Create("◊", "&loz;", "&#9674;"), // Lozenge
 Tuple.Create("♠", "&spades;", "&#9824;"), // Spade
 Tuple.Create("♣", "&clubs;", "&#9827;"), // Club
 Tuple.Create("♥", "&hearts;", "&#9829;"), // Heart
 Tuple.Create("♦", "&diams;", "&#9830;") // Diamond
};

private static string ConvertToHtmlEntities(string value) {
 if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) {
  return value;
 }

 var result = _htmlEntities.Where(t => t.Item1 == "&").Aggregate(value, (r, t) => r.Replace(t.Item1, t.Item2));
 result = _htmlEntities.Where(t => t.Item1 != "&").Aggregate(result, (r, t) => r.Replace(t.Item1, t.Item2));
 return result;
}
```

[image: current result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a way, using the [AntiXSS library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AntiXSS/) which was announced to be [End of life](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=wpl) (except for security fixes if needed).

So it isn't deprecated or obsolete, just no longer very actively maintained because parts that Microsoft considered essential have been ported into .NET Framework v4.0. And it looks they did not port the part that we need here.

*Steps to take:*

(1) Through NuGet package manager, add `AntiXSS` to your project.

(2) Write your code like this:

```
var text = "Viel Spaß damit!";
var encoded = Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.HtmlEncode(text, useNamedEntities: true);
```

Result:

```html
Viel Spa&szlig; damit!
```